# Software to efficiently manage my office work

Tags: osx, project-management, wiki, information-management, office

After some years of experience and trials, I've found out that for me (and for many around there) the best tool to work efficiently would be software which allows to search and access from one single interface:

1. emails
2. files
3. notes
4. calendars (events and tasks)

Most of my office work is usually done by sending / receiving emails, writing documents and notes, setting up events and tasks.
It would be important to link those 4 object types. E.g. I would like to write a note where I point (hyperlink) to an email, or attach documents to an event.

It is of course possible to have single applications / softwares which, used together in a PC desktop environment, do the job fine. With Google Tools, for example, we are almost there: we have efficient email, a calendar where I can put attachment taken from google drive...

There are also some intersting MacOSX mail extension which can help (e.g. [Devonthink](http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_144223661432312&key=3398740902e69bebff28e573e9cf33ab&libId=iejyfllr010021b4000DAkg8qbwse&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.macworld.com%2Farticle%2F2140903%2Fmy-nine-must-have-plug-ins-for-apple-mail.html&v=1&out=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.devontechnologies.com%2Fproducts%2Fdevonthink%2Fdevonthink-pro-office.html&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.it%2F&title=My%20nine%20must-have%20plug-ins%20for%20Apple%20Mail%20%7C%20Macworld&txt=DEVONthink%20Pro%20Office&loAsUuid=iejyflxs-90dd90a1-b527-4b1f-8f46-74f1cdc073d6))...but that always miss that something...

Well, this solution could be fine but it requires to be always online.

What I need, in the end, is a sort of local wiki where I can store structured information. Evernote works well, it is somehow integrable with gmail (with a paying tool) but in the end it is still a note-taking program.

Do you know of any software which works as a local wiki and that can store/serach all my data?

Answer (score 1):

**[nValt](http://brettterpstra.com/projects/nvalt/)** is a minimal, terribly effective solution search-wise, despite still being just a note-taking application (cloud and mobile enabled).

Have a look at it and read around... many blog posts from Evernote->nValt switchers.

The global search over mail, files, calendars and notes can only be solved by moving completely to a cloud based management of your digital assets and forget about desktop apps (big mental shift even for the 30-something!). [Wrike](http://wrike.com) (not free) quite gets it, with the full stack of collaborative tools for project management added.

Comment: "global search over mail, files, calendars and notes can only be solved by moving completely to a cloud based management": Why? If all that data is available locally, I don't see why a local solution cannot work. Pure cloud-based management of *all* data might not be an option as soon as it comes to sensible information – and compromising that just for a "convenient search" is not a good answer IMHO.

Comment: yes sorry, you're right the security issue can be relevant; I was thinking more into enlarging the subject to also cover sharing and collaboration, and access from diferent devices, sooner or later you will need these features during your activities.

Comment: That might be. But then you keep security in mind when deciding what to sync with "somebody else's computers" (aka "the cloud"). To me, that would still mean all data available locally – and just selected documents/details "synced globally". But YMMV :)